# Angular-cli including ngAudio into your project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

installed ngAudio from http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/.
after the install I should include it in the app.module.ts before I can use it in my project.

I'm rather at a loss on how to include it here, because the standard "Require the module in your project: angular.module('yourModule',['ngAudio'])" that they say on the website does not make any sense to me.

my app.module.ts is as follows:

```
//Modules
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';

//routes
const appRoutes: Route[] =
    [
        { path: "soundwave", component: SoundwaveComponent },
        { path: "weather", component: WeatherComponent },
        { path: "movies", component: MoviesComponent },
        { path: "moviesearch", component: MoviesearchComponent },
        { path: "news", component: NewsComponent },
    ]

//services
import { TmdbService } from './services/tmdb.service';
import { NewsService } from './services/news.service';
import { WeatherService } from './services/weather.service';
import { SoundwaveService } from './services/soundwave.service';


//Angular Material
import { MdButtonModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule } from '@angular/material';

//special
import 'hammerjs';


//component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MoviesComponent } from './movies/movies.component';
import { MoviesearchComponent } from './moviesearch/moviesearch.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { SoundwaveComponent } from './soundwave/soundwave.component';
import { WeatherComponent } from './weather/weather.component';

//Pipes
import { RoundPipe } from './pipes/round.pipe';
import { SubmitOnEnterDirective } from './directives/submit-on-enter.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, MoviesComponent, MoviesearchComponent, NewsComponent, SoundwaveComponent, WeatherComponent, RoundPipe, SubmitOnEnterDirective],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        MdButtonModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [TmdbService, NewsService, WeatherService, SoundwaveService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Folder structure that I'm using:

[image]

Comment: This lib is for AngularJs, not Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is for AngularJS, not Angular. You won't be able to easily add it into your current project.

Working with audio in Angular is more on the JS side than anything. Angular has all the buttons and services, but you'll want to use javascript for working with the audio. I'd suggest using a popular javascript package available with npm. [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation) is available and easily integrated into any Angular-CLI project just like any other npm package.

You can check out [this](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/727) issue for installation.

Comment: Is there an other package that you could suggest for me to use? I am trying to activate audio by push of a button.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thnx for the answer. I will be checking this out :)